# What should i do to test EasyMock objects when using Generics ? EasyMock

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, easymock

See code just bellow

Our generic interface

```
public interface Repository<INSTANCE_CLASS, INSTANCE_ID_CLASS> {

    void add(INSTANCE_CLASS instance);
    INSTANCE_CLASS getById(INSTANCE_ID_CLASS id);

}
```

And a single class

```
public class Order {

    private Integer id;
    private Integer orderNumber;

    // getter's and setter's

    public void equals(Object o) {
        if(o == null)
            return false;

        if(!(o instanceof Order))
            return false;

        // business key
        if(getOrderNumber() == null)
            return false;

        final Order other = (Order) o;
        if(!(getOrderNumber().equals(other.getOrderNumber())))
            return false;

        return true;    
    }

    // hashcode

}
```

And when i do the following test

```
private Repository<Order, Integer> repository;

@Before
public void setUp {

    repository = EasyMock.createMock(Repository.class);

    Order order = new Order();
    order.setOrderNumber(new Integer(1));

    repository.add(order);

    EasyMock.expectLasCall().once();
    EasyMock.replay(repository);
}

@Test
public void addOrder() {
    Order order = new Order();
    order.setOrderNumber(new Integer(1));

    repository.add(order);

    EasyMock.verify(repository)
}
```

I get

```
Unexpected method call add(br.com.smac.model.domain.Order@ac66b62):
    add(br.com.smac.model.domain.Order@ac66b62): expected: 1, actual: 0
        at org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:43)
        at org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:72)
        at $Proxy4.add(Unknown Source)
```

Why does it not work as expected ??? What should i do to pass the test ??? Any workaround ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your code and ran it with Java 1.6 using EasyMock 2.0 and it works just fine. I had to fix some parts like `public void equals(Object o)` which should be `public boolean equals`, but it seems clear that you had it right in your real code.
Are you using another EasyMock version or do I miss something?

Cheers
Thomas

Comment: @Thomas Thans for your reply, Thomas. ok about boolean equals. Have you done as shown above ? I am using 2.5.2 version

Comment: @Arthur I changed it to 2.5.2 and it still works, from command line and in eclipse. I really copy pasted all your code as it is written above and added getters and setters.

Comment: You are right. I missed some code in equals implementation. Accepted. Good to know EasyMock supports Generic

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. I recomend Mockito for better readability (http://mockito.org/). It's a fork of EasyMock and includes the EasyMock ClassExtensions in the default package.